# HTML5 tag not working in windows safari 5.1 browser

Tags: safari, html5-video, safari-web-inspector

I am trying to create an html5 web page in which there is a small video like 13s , I converted the flash version of this video into 3 format : mp4, ogg, webm.

```
<video id="banner-video" poster="images/example.jpg" class="video" muted loop autoplay>
        <source src="media/example.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        <source src="media/example.ogg" type="video/ogg">
        <source src="media/example.webm" type="video/webm">
      </video>
```

It is proper working in Windows PC (Mozilla firebox, Google Chrome, IE10, 11 (Show only video banner)), Mac PC (Safari, Chrome), IPhone and IPad. 
But is not working in only Safari.

I am create using this type code.
Demo Link : http://vodkabears.github.io/vide/

Comment: Could you share your code for video tag? For the link that you shared its working in safari browser.

Comment: Hello Nikhila 84, I have added demo link in my question. I using this demo same code. Can you please go the link and check code. Thanks